# PHP Codeigniter randomize db record sequence

Tags: codeigniter, random

I got a Codeigniter PHP application each page will display one questions, now I want random display the questions sequence. I understand can be done in this way

```
SELECT * FROM questions **ORDER BY RAND()**
```

But the problem is my question display one each page, pagination. If doing this way, the questions will be repeated any idea how to random the sequence without included previous shown data. And because the system allows user to go back previous and next first last questions. If random the question will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Get previous all question into array,when u get new question using rand() method, check those value exit on array

Answer (score 0):

You could store the previous shown data ($previous_ids) in a session:

```
//after retrieving add to session
$previous_ids = $this->session->userdata('previous_ids');
$previous_ids[] = $randomly_retrieved_id;

$this->session->set_userdata('previous_ids', $previous_ids);

//use session data when retrieving next id
$this->db->where_not_in('id', $previous_ids)
         ->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
         ->get('questions');
```